# Can Apache POI convert an Excel file to CSV without parsing?

Tags: java, excel, csv, pom.xml

Does anyone know if I can use something like Apache POI to convert an Excel file into CSV file in Java without application to parse into it?

Answer (score 1):

Well, there needs to be some application, but you don't have to write it yourself.

I think there is no such ready-made tool included in POI itself, but other people have made such things and you can probably (disclaimer: I have not tried any) use them, for example

- https://github.com/anjlab/excel2csv-java
- http://code.google.com/p/excel2csv/

Note that this is bound to work only for very simple Excel files, as the Excel workbook format supports a lot of stuff that cannot be expressed in CSV.